# Specify Lifetime For Durable Products in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

The windows store declares that if you create a durable product with a lifetime other than forever, it will be available only for Windows Phone 8.1 users. How can I deal with Windows Phone 8, if I want a product to last only for 30 days and not forever?

Comment: are you sure you mean Windows 8.1 and not Windows Phone 8.1? Please edit to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your title and tags that you mean Windows Phone 8, not Windows 8. Windows 8 supports expiring durables.

Windows Phone 8 doesn't support expiring durables, but you can use a consumable and either not fulfill it for 30 days or fulfill it but not offer it again for 30 days.

--Rob

Comment: So to check if the subscription is over I would have to call:
CurrentApp.GetProductReceiptAsync(key)
And check the purchase date in the XML result?